# How to change background color to transparent in gimp?

Tags: gimp

I am trying to change the background color within gimp to transparent following [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5446/making-the-background-of-an-image-transparent-in-gimp) suggestion but it does not seem to work.

1. Select the object with the "Fuzzy select tool"
2. Go to Colors -> Color to Alpha and click 'OK'.

But the result does not look like as given in the example, here is what I see:

[image]

I do not the the checkerboarder background. I also tried to invert the selection before. And I do not understand what this 'From' color is supposed to mean:

[image]

The preview looks exactly as I want to have it. But still, the background keeps white and does not get transparent. Is there something I am doing wrong or what I am missing?

Comment: Did you enable the alpha-channel? Easiest way to chek is using the eraser. If you don't get the checkerboard then, this might be your problem.

Comment: I think I have the alpha channel enabled. The channel-window shows four channels

Comment: Also with the eraser, the background stays white and does not change to the checkerboard thingy

Comment: Do you have multiple layers in your image?

Comment: I created the image 'new' and put in the letter X. Thats all I have been doing

Comment: Did you join the text with the layer below?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98476/discussion-between-alex-and-hermann-doppes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you didn't join your text to the lower layer, your BG already was transparent and the white of the layer below was shining through. By merging the layers, you can apply your technique.

Alternatively you can remove the BG layer or make it invisible. However, this approach generalises worse, as you keep the shape of the text layer, which may not be what you want.